# Getting id_token as null in OIDC when sending responseType = 'id_token'

Tags: openid-connect, okta

I am using OKTA where after login getting id_token as a response in url. The problem is whenever i call this.oauthService.getIdToken() i am getting null. Below is my configuration.

```
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://dev-350189.okta.com',
  clientId: "XXXXXXX",
  logoutUrl: "https://dev-350189.okta.com/oauth2/v1/logout",
  redirectUri: window.location.origin +'/home',
  scope: 'openid profile',
  responseType: 'id_token',
  oidc: true,
  requestAccessToken: true,
  showDebugInformation: true,
  clearHashAfterLogin: false,
}
```

app.component.ts

```
private configure() {
        this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
        this.oauthService.setStorage(localStorage);
        this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();

        this.oauthService.createAndSaveNonce().then(nonce => {
            console.log('Nonce generated', nonce);
            this.oauthService.customQueryParams = { "nonce": nonce };

            // Load Discovery Document and then try to login the user
            this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
                this.oauthService.tryLogin().then(() => {
                    console.log("final output");
                    console.log(this.oauthService.getIdToken());
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Please help guys i am struggling since 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working Okta sample that may help - try using equivalent settings to [my settings](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts).

The most standard flow these days is response_type='code', meaning Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) - which Okta fully supports.

If it helps the sample has a README file that links to some blog posts